# Wanting to add a 80 amp subpanel to my upstairs rooms. My house was built in the 1870's so electric was an afterthought

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, subpanel

My house was built in the 1870's and the electric was an afterthought. Currently my 3 br upstairs is be fed by a single 20 amp breaker . I want to add an 80 amp sub to isolate the upstairs and have each room on its own 20A service. To feed the sub from the main, do I add 2 40A breakers and use them as the feed?

Comment: Add your location, please. Electrical codes are different per jurisdiction.

Comment: Should decide between want and need.  Can feed a 80 amp sub panel from any size breaker at or below 80 amps.  Bedrooms usually do not need much power, unless you use electric space heaters in them.  One 40 amp breaker will be enough to feed the sub panel with three 20 amp breakers.  You do not now trip the single 20 amp breaker?

Comment: I like to have at least two circuits serve each room.  That way you can plug in a work light while working on the ceiling light, or use the ceiling light while working on the outlets, etc., without running cords through the hall.   It's also easy to install adjacent outlets serving two rooms sharing a wall from one circuit, and a lot more effort to isolate the rooms from one another.

Comment: Actually, going 90A would have the advantage of the wire being cheaper than even 40A wire.  Since you said 80A from four 20A circuits, it sounds like you don't know [the secret about North American electric](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jMmUoZh3Hq4).

Answer (score 5):

Presuming from context that you are in the US or Canada, you put one 40A **two-pole breaker** in the supply, which provides **40A @ 240V**  (9600W) to your subpanel, and then you can supply **four 20A @ 120V**  (*also* 9600W) circuits from the subpanel without overloading the supply.

The supply to the panel is controlled by the 40A two-pole breaker **in the main panel.** The subpanel needs to be *at least* 40A (not 80), but *much more is fine.* The actual amperage rating **of the panel** might be 100A or more in order to ensure adequate spaces for current needs while permitting for future expansion without running out of breaker spaces.

However - Note that in many/most cases the breakers from a subpanel can exceed the supply to it (if just added up) as each circuit is not normally fully loaded. You can determine the minimum appropriate amount of power to supply by doing a **load calculation** for the area served. You can, of course, supply more than the minimum required.

Of note - if there's a bathroom on the floor, you should plan to supply that with a 20A circuit of its own. And you can very likely do that without making the supply to the sub-panel larger. You might want lighting or hallway lighting to be on a separate 15A breaker - which, again, probably does not require increasing the supply. But check the load calculation.

***Additional note:** In "an 1870 house with electric as an after thought" (of course, it wasn't a utility yet in 1870) you should firmly embrace Arc Fault Circuit Interrupters, even if your local applicable code does not require them, yet. They do cost a bit more, but they might also save your house and/or life by preventing an electrical fire. Fire safety wasn't much of a thought at all in construction practices of the time, in most locations.*